# wordpress custom post type meta field value

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following multidimensional array in wordpress from custom post type. The custom post type name is: "**references**"

How can I get the following values: **reference_page_lead** and **reference_page_url** ?

```
array(4) {
  ["_edit_last"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["_edit_lock"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "1424697906:1"
  }
  ["_reference"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(189) "a:2:{s:19:"reference_page_lead";s:95:"A Lorem Ipsum egy egyszerû szövegrészlete, szövegutánzata a betûszedõ és nyomdaiparnak.";s:18:"reference_page_url";s:19:"https://lorem.ipsum";}"
  }
  ["_thumbnail_id"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "36"
  }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, I resolved:

```
        $reference_data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_reference', true );

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($reference_data);
        echo "</pre>";

        foreach ( $reference_data as $key => $value ) {
            echo "<pre>";
            echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
            echo "</pre>";
        }

       $reference_data["reference_page_lead"];
       $reference_data["reference_page_url"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is serialized, so you'll need to unserialize it.

[Reference to unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

```
$result = unserialize($theArray["_reference"][0]);

echo $result['reference_page_url'];
echo $result['reference_page_lead'];
```

Comment: Just noticed that _reference is an array, updated the example above ^^